# Socket IO : Best way to retrieve socket of specific connected client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, mean-stack

I am trying build a chat server using MEAN Stack **(not using redis)**, which uses socket.io for enabling real time chat. For private messaging, I want to implement the built-in "room" feature of socket.io. The flow goes as follows :

User1 wants to start a conversation with User2, so User1 emits an event, which the server catches.
In the server, I store this conversation in database and join User1 to a room. If User2 is online, then I join **User2 also to this room**. For achieving this step, I need access to the socket of User2. 
After a good amount of research, I found this method to store the "socket" of every connected user in an array(or dictionary). 
I was wondering if there is any other method to retrieve the socket other than storing it in an array.

Answer (score 0):

No, no better way, except if you use different namespace for the two users, but i don't think it's your case.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a basic POC (proof of concept) a couple years ago using [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html).

In my case I created a unique channel for active users. The channel name was the same as the unique user identifier from mongo ( _id ). This allowed me to send messages to the correct user without having to store information about their connection.

Please note that I did not do any performance testing and that you would need to have a lot of connections open.

I did a similar implementation using faye by broadcasting to channels, in that case I did store in the database who was connected to a specific channel.